# Problema guardando orden de imagenes en Base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

tengo un problema guardando el orden de mis imagenes en la base de datos,primero tengo un archivo JS donde almaceno el nuevo orden en una variable, al ahcer un console.log, si me lo muestra correctamente, luego mando esos datos a un archivo AJAX que lo manda al controlador y luego al modelo, pero este ultimo no guarda el orden en la DB, y no me muestra ningun error, pongo el codigo, esperando alguien pueda ver algo que yo no.

NOTA* solo pongo las lineas de codigo correspondientes al orden, omitiendo clases y cosas innecesarias, sin embargo, si necesitan mas informacion, con gusto la pondre, tambien he omitido rutas y nombres de tablas.

Muchas gracias (=

JS

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('#desul li').length; i++)
{
   almacenarOrdenId[i] = event.target.children[i].id;
   ordenItem[i] = i+1;
}

$('#btnDesignPortSave').click(function(){

for(var i = 0; i < $('#desul li').length; i++)
{
    var actualizarOrden = new FormData();
    actualizarOrden.append("actualizarOrdenGaleria", almacenarOrdenId[i]);
    actualizarOrden.append("actualizarOrdenItem", ordenItem[i]);

    $.ajax({

        url:"PATH TO AJAX FILE",
        method: "POST",
        data: actualizarOrden,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(respuesta)
        {
            $('#desport ul').html(respuesta);

            swal("Order updated", {
                buttons: false,
                timer: 2000,
            }).then(
                function(){
                    window.location = "designPortfolio";
                }
            );
          }
      })//ajax
   }//for

})//Btn
```

AJAX FILE

```
public $actualizarOrdenGaleria;
public $actualizarOrdenItem;

public function actualizarDordenAjax()
{

    $datos = array("ordenGaleria" => $this -> actualizarOrdenGaleria,
                    "ordenItem" => $this -> actualizarOrdenItem);

    $respuesta = gestorDgaleriaController::actualizarOrdenController($datos);

    echo $respuesta;

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

if(isset($POST["actualizarOrdenGaleria"]))
{
   $c = new Ajax();
   $c -> actualizarOrdenGaleria = $_POST["actualizarOrdenGaleria"];
   $c -> actualizarOrdenItem = $_POST["actualizarOrdenItem"];
   $c -> actualizarDordenAjax();

}
```

PHP

```
////CONTROLLER

public function actualizarOrdenController($datos)
{
    gestorDgaleriaModel::actualizarOrdenModel($datos,"DB TABLE");
    $respuesta = gestorDgaleriaModel::seleccionarOrdenModel("DB TABLE");

    foreach($respuesta as $row => $item)
    {
        echo'<li id="'.$item["id"].'" class="bloqueDGaleria">
                <i class="fa fa-times delbtn portdesdel" aria-hidden="true" ruta="'.$item["ruta"].'"></i>
                <a data-fancybox="portdes" href="'.substr($item["ruta"],6).'">
                    <img src="'.substr($item["ruta"],6).'" class="handleDImg"/>
                </a>
            </li>';


    }

}

////MODEL

public function actualizarOrdenModel($datos,$tabla)
{
    $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET orden = :orden WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":orden", $datos["ordenItem"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $datos["ordenGaleria"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        return "ok";
    }
    else
    {
        return "error";
    }

    $stmt -> close();


}


public function seleccionarOrdenModel($tabla)
{
    $stmt = conexion::conectar()-> prepare("SELECT id, ruta FROM $tabla ORDER BY orden ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fecthAll();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca el ajax con el atributo **async: false**, eso hará que se inserten una por una en orden, creo que con eso debería de solventarte tu problema:

```
$.ajax({

        url:"PATH TO AJAX FILE",
        method: "POST",
        data: actualizarOrden,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
...
```

Esto hace que la siguiente foto o imagen que vayas a subir espere aque la anterior sea guardada.

Me avisas como te fue.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, intente con el atributo async: false, pero no resolvio mi problema, el orden sigue sin guardarse

Comment: es raro, estoy casi seguro que es que el ajax al estar asyncrono por defecto el va guardando la primera que se le atraviese por así decirlo, me puedes mostrar el console.log de actualizarOrden justo antes de invocar el ajax por favor

Comment: La otra seria armar el valor de actualizarOrden antes de llamar al ajax con su for como lo tienes, es decir no llamar el ajax tanta veces hagas el for sino una sola vez.

Comment: Claro que si, te mando la captura del console.log, espero te sirva, dime si necesitas algo mas por favor =D 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xHOe1dMpSkHAykgLhBG5p6CVdmmu1vUh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Estuve intentando llenar la variable actualizarOrden con el ciclo for y afuera de este invocar el ajax como comentas, pero aun asi no funciona, no se que esta pasando jaja x)

Comment: ok llenas la variable antes de llamar al ajax, luego en el php dale un print_r() del array donde estan las imagenes a ver si te mantiene el orden, me avisas, es para descartar el js

Comment: Es una buena respuesta pero... ¿no bloqueará la IU mientras se hace la subida? Igual este detalle le interesa al OP.

Comment: si puede ser, pero la idea es verlo por la consola, cuando el ajax hace la peticion y luego le das un print_r en la consola deberias de ver la peticion al php y el php mostrarte en consola el resultado del print_r, la idea es ver si estan llegando las imagenes ordenadas al php para descartar definitivamente el js

Comment: Hola, una disculpa primero que nada por la demora en contestar, estuve intentando con el print_r, pero no me muestra nada en consola, incluso estuve haciendo pruebas con variables de prueba, llamandolas en js y mostrarlas en consola, pero tampoco funciono, incluso cree otro archivo ajax y volvi a repetir todo el proceso, pro si omiti algo, pero tampoco funciono =/

Comment: y en la BD si te esta guardando las imagenes? te pregunto porque con el print_r deberias de verlo, estas subiendo archivos cierto? o solo los nombre de las imagenes? si son archivos tienes que darle un print_r a $_FILES

Comment: Si me guarda las imagenes, subo archivos y guardo los nombre, todo me funciona bien, puedo subir imagenes y borrarlas, pero no puedo ordenarlas.

Porque a $_FILES ? osea lo que quiero hacer es ordenar las imagenes que ya estan subidas, en ningun momento uso $_FILES para el orden, mas bien utilizo un $POST para saber si la variable trae algo, intente un print_r tambien, pero no me muestra nada, tambien le di un print_r a la variable $datos que es donde guardo el array que viene de JS, pero tampoco me muestra nada

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo entendido que cuando subes archivos por ajax como lo estas haciendo tu para ver en PHP esos archivos le haces un print_r a $_FILES no a $_POST, y podras ver el tmp, name etc, yo he intentado hacerlo con $_POST y no funciona ver los archivos, apenas llegues al PHP a traves de la petición ajax haz un print_r($_FILES) y muestrame lo que te muestra el ajax por la consola en su peticion por favor, ahi veremos en realidad como estan llegando las imagenes ordenadas al php antes de guardar, acuerdate de darle un exit despues del print_r

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, ahh que verguenza, el error esta en el $_POST, yo puse $POST, por eso no me mostraba el print_r, de hecho en el codigo de arriba ahi sale:

if(isset($POST["actualizarOrdenGaleria"]))

pero cuando pusiste $_POST me cayo el 20 x), 2 dias de frustracion por un maldito "_", pero asi es el magico mundo de la programacion verdad.

En fin muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio bastante =D

Comment: Que bueno que pudieras resolver, saludos y siempre a la orden